# Problem reading values column headers to csv in robot framework

Tags: encoding, automation, robotframework

When exporting a column header from web menu to CSV in Robot framework, the language is polish the text identifies unknown charcters. How to encode it?

[image]

Comment: this is orginal text which i am supposed to get Stan, Nr urządzenia, Typ urządzenia, ID tabliczki znamionowej, Dokładny typ, Obszar, Numer seryjny, Nr urządzenia Master, 
Liczniki, Jakość kom., Aktualizacja firmware status, Czas statusu                                                  But i get this Stan', 'Nr urz\u0105dzenia', 'Typ urz\u0105dzenia', 'ID tabliczki znamionowej', 'Dok\u0142adny typ', 'Obszar', 'Numer seryjny', 
'Nr urz\u0105dzenia Master', 'Liczniki', 'Jako\u015b\u0107 kom.', 'Aktualizacja firmware status', 'Czas statusu'

Comment: Can you update the original question with the additional data? Have you looked at the encoding?

Comment: Sorry i understood the problem is not with encoding,the list compares the two list for sub list values ,but the csv file has double quotes inside it and when it compares to other list it throws error.Do you know how to remove the double quotes in csv by robot framework.

Comment: This is a different question to your original i suggest creating a new question with your code provided

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem you are seeing above is to do with encoding. The result from 
`Get column headers from CSV file` isn't a list which is what your error is pointing too.

[List Should Contain Sub List](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#List%20Should%20Contain%20Sub%20List) is expecting 2 lists as args

Comment: you are right ,the list compares the two strings for sub list values ,but the csv file has double quotes inside it and when it compares to other list it throws error.Do you know how to remove the double quotes in csv by robot framework.